# How to change font-size of one section in materialize css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, materialize

I'm trying to fit in one page section large amount of text. I use materialize css framework on my website, but I don't know how to change the font-size in this one section.

Here is my section:

```css
#submissions {
  font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<section id="submissions" class="white">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="section">
        <br/><br/>
        <h4 class="text-grey center-align">Submissions</h4>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="col s6">
          <!-- And here is a lot of content that I want to contain -->
          test test  test test  test test  test test  test test  test test 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

To do this I'm trying to use styles.css something like this:

```
#submissions {
    font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

Can anyone can advise me something?

Comment: i did'nt get exactly what yo want! but its working just increase font size.. - https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/Ldv73kfb/

Comment: Do you only want to change the size of the text ....test test.....

Please add more details to your question ATM is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

materializecss doesn't have any native support for changing font-size so you are going to have to either add a separate id or class to hook your css.

in case you only want to change the font-size of the contained text (add #csshook to your stylesheet):

```
<div class="col s6" id="csshook">
       <!-- And here is a lot of content that I want to contain -->
       test test  test test  test test  test test  test test  test test 
</div>
```

in case you want to do both headers and text (add .csshook to your stylesheet):

```
h4 class="text-grey center-align csshook">Submissions</h4>
<div class="divider"></div>
   <div class="col s6 csshook">
      <!-- And here is a lot of content that I want to contain -->
      test test  test test  test test  test test  test test  test test 
   </div>
```

depending on which result you prefer use the id or class to change the font-size.

also make sure you initialize your stylesheet **AFTER** the materializecss stylesheet in your page.

Answer (score 2):

The default stylesheet that materialize serves can be customised to your hearts content with Sass. (You should be using Sass anyway becasue it's [awesome](https://materializecss.com/sass.html)).

Download the [Sass version](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html), and inside you'll find a scss file for each component. In _typography.scss the global font size is set at the start:

```
html{
  line-height: 1.5;

  @media only screen and (min-width: 0) {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width: $medium-screen) {
    font-size: 14.5px;
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width: $large-screen) {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  font-family: $font-stack;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: $off-black;
}
```

You can see here that we start at 14px and move up to 15px responsively. If you change this and save, the sass will automatically re-compile a materialize.css with the updated values. Note if you want to change the global settings for header tags, you can do so in _variables.scss:

```
$font-stack: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif !default;
$off-black: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87) !default;
// Header Styles
$h1-fontsize: 4.2rem !default;
$h2-fontsize: 3.56rem !default;
$h3-fontsize: 2.92rem !default;
$h4-fontsize: 2.28rem !default;
$h5-fontsize: 1.64rem !default;
$h6-fontsize: 1.15rem !default;
```

Lastly, it's not good praqctice to have text floating loose in a div. I would wrap in a p tag:

```
<div class="col s6">
          <!-- And here is a lot of content that I want to contain -->
          <p>test test  test test  test test  test test  test test  test test</p>
        </div>
```

And actually lastly, you can always override the base font size in your css file like this:

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using "id" and "class" to identify element which isn't correct.

Try as below.

```
<section id="submissions">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both text in large size just add same class in `<section class="something">` and `<div class="col s6 domething">`

```css
.submissions {
  font-size: 25px !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="white submissions">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="section">
        <br/><br/>
        <h4 class="text-grey center-align">Submissions</h4>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="col s6 submissions">
          <!-- And here is a lot of content that I want to contain -->
          test test test test test test test test test test test test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

or

Try two diff classes..

```css
.submissions {
  font-size: 25px !important;
}

.submis {
  font-size: 18px !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="white submissions">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <div class="section">
        <br/><br/>
        <h4 class="text-grey center-align">Submissions</h4>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="col s6 submis">
          <!-- And here is a lot of content that I want to contain -->
          test test test test test test test test test test test test
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```